# “End of the world” anthology book, including a story about the onset of a new ice age, and another about a meteor destroying a large city

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, apocalypse

I’ve been trying to find a book I had checked out from my local library in the early 1980s.  It was an anthology of short stories about end of the world.

Title had the word “catastrophe” or “catastrophes” (or possibly “cataclysms”) and cover showed the Earth, possibly being swallowed by the Sun.
Here is what I remember about the stories:

- One was about the onset of a new ice age. I think the story covered a wide range of time. Story started with a man shoveling his driveway…in Florida. Story ended with humanity deciding to go into cryogenic sleep in a mountain-based facility and wait out the ice age; however, this apparently is unsuccessful as it ends with “when the ice broke through the locks.”
- Another story has a meteor destroying a large city, but before this is known, the male protagonist wonders what happened, speculating it was a nuclear attack by China.
- Another story features a star near the Earth going nova and the slow destruction of the Earth as a result.

I’ve found similar stories (some famous) to these scenarios, but they’re either novels, or not quite right.  It does not appear to be “Catastrophes!” by Asimov. If anyone can help me find it, I would be grateful!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: For the second one (meteor destroys city): Is it Washington DC that's destroyed by what the US military assumes to is a decapitating nuclear strike, and a lone US military officer in a bunker, whose responsibility it is to launch a retaliatory strike, waits and resists pressure to launch, until it's eventually determined that it was a meteor and nuclear war is averted? If so, I can't find it yet, but hoping the details help someone else.